# SQL Query Performance in Jupyter Notebook (Python Teradatasql package) vs. TeraData SQL Assistant Performance

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, teradata-sql-assistant

Why would a SQL query in TeraData SQL Assistant (or any SQL manager) run faster than in a Jupyter Notebook using Python (i.e. SQLAlchemy / TeraDatasql packages)?

What is the technical reasoning?

Comment: show us how you load data in your python code

Comment: The actual query (inside the database) should be no different. The difference is whatever additional processing of the data is occurring on the client side (e.g. building a dataframe).